# NodeJS programs fail, exiting with no output

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu-14.04, grover

Several of my node programs are exiting with a failure status and no output. E.g.:

```js
$ npmunbox --help  # Error - no output
$ grover --version  # Error - no output
```

Even though my nodejs seems to be working fine:

```js
$ nodejs --version
v0.10.32
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that I had a package called "node - Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)" (note: this is NOT nodejs) installed:

```sh
$ dpkg -l | grep node
ii  ax25-node                                             0.3.2-7.4                                           amd64        Amateur Packet Radio Node program
ii  node                                                  0.3.2-7.4                                           amd64        Amateur Packet Radio Node program
ii  nodejs                                                0.10.32-1chl1~trusty1                               amd64        Node.js event-based server-side javascript engi
```

This binary is at `/usr/bin/node`, but some `nodejs` programs expect to find the binary for `nodejs` here.

The trick is to uninstall the `node` package, and then re-install `nodejs`:

```js
$ sudo apt-get purge node nodejs  # Uninstall both
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs  # Reinstall nodejs
```

Now the `/usr/bin/node` binary should be linked to `nodejs` (in a somewhat roundabout way):

```js
$ ls -l /usr/bin/node /etc/alternatives/node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 18 15:57 /etc/alternatives/node -> /usr/bin/nodejs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 18 15:57 /usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node
```

And your nodejs programs should now work correctly:

```js
$ npmunbox --help
npmunbox - Extracts a .npmbox file and installs the contained package.
...
$ grover --version
0.1.17
```

Comment: It might be interesting to know how you out about this conflict. I think that running `which node` doesn't help much.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Well, when I ran `dpkg -l | grep node` and saw that `node` didn't have anything like the correct version number, that is what clued me in.

Comment: Ohhhh.. That's a superfast find. `Asked` time and `Answered` time is the same and by the same person.. :-)

Comment: @AnishNair: Given that stackoverflow is a great place for people to find solutions, you're doing a service by posting a self-answered question, meaning other people can find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If You have already installed nodejs along side node (unrelated to node.js)
instead of `node --version` use `nodejs --version`